# Make div inside parent 100% width of body, not parent div

Tags: css, width

I want to make my inner div 100% width of the body, not 100% of the parent div. Is this possible?

The layout looks like this:

```
<body>
   <div> /** Width:900px; **/
      <div> /** This I want 100% of BODY, not of parent div **/

      </div>
   </div>
</body>
```

Comment: What is the actual use case?

Comment: I want the background of the second div to go all the way to the edges of the window.

Comment: What is the background? A solid colour? An image?

Comment: The background is an image.

Answer (score 11):

i hope you are looking like this........... see the [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/ygXy6/13/)

[**UPDATED DEMO 2 AS PER YOUR CURRENT REQUIREMENTS**](http://jsfiddle.net/ygXy6/18/)

**CSS**

```
    .parent {
background:red;
width:900px;
margin:0 auto;
padding:10px;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}

.inner {
background:green;
height:100px;
position:absolute;
  left:0;
  right:0;
}

.child {
  height:100px;
  background:black;
  margin:10px 0;
}
```

-------------********

**Second Answer** with without positioning but with a some trick what i used here so please check it the code & demo mentioned below :-

**HTML**

```
<body>
   <div class="parent"> /** Width:900px; **/
  <div class="child"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="inner"> /** This I want 100% of BODY, not of parent div  **/</div>
   <div class="parent">
       <div class="child"></div>
       <div class="child"></div>
   </div>
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
.parent {
background:red;
width:900px;
margin:0 auto;
padding:10px;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}

.inner {
background:green;
height:100px;
}

.child {
  height:100px;
  background:black;
  margin:10px 0;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/ygXy6/23/)

Comment: Maybe I misleaded you. The second div I want all the way out to the edges, but there will be other divs putted over and other the 100% one. So position absolute will get wrong result.

Comment: @DanielLundahl this is not possible without position absolute if you are not used to position absolute than you change to the your html Than it's Possible .....

Comment: can you post your desired result image what exactly you are looking ?

Comment: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/231/layoutna.jpg/
Here is a drawing of the result I'm looking for

Comment: Well, that does look right, but I can't build it that way. Im working with drupal (CMS) and I can't change the layout because of the system (It's rebuilded by another company). So, if there is no way of doing this with just CSS or maybe some javascript, then I have to consider using another design :(

Comment: :-) you can think because sometimes we have to adjust according to limitations & parameters....

Answer (score 5):

you can use vh an vw units

```css
.parent {
  width: 900px;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: red;
}
.child {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
   <div class="parent"> 
      <div class="child"> 

      </div>
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```css
.inner {
  margin-left: -50vw;
  left: 50%;
  position: fixed;
  height: 100vw;
  width: 100vw;
  top: 0;
}

.outer {
  width: 900px;
  /* your outer div style*/
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="outer"> /** Width:900px; **/
    <div class="inner"> /** This 100% of BODY, not of parent div **/

    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are asking for isn't possible. Instead you should consider rethinking your layout. I often find myself doing stuff like this:

html:

```
<div id="top">
    <div class="wrapper"></div>
</div>
<div id="content">
    <div class="wrapper"></div>
</div>
<div id="footer">
    <div class="wrapper"></div>
</div>
```

css:

```
#top {
  background: red;
}

#content {
  background: orange;
}

#footer {
  background: yellow;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 860px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 20px;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
}
```

demo - http://jsfiddle.net/bxGH2/

Answer (score 0):

Consider changing your layoiut to something like the following:

http://jsfiddle.net/KpTHz/

Then you can just apply ID tags to DIVs you want to apply specific rules to.

```
<div class="outer">
 <div class="inner">HEADER</div>
</div>

<div class="outer">
 <div class="inner">CONTENT</div>
</div>

<div class="outer">
 <div class="inner">FOOTER</div>
</div>


.outer {
 width:100%;
 background:#ccc;
}

.inner {
 width:920px;
 background:#999;
 margin:0 auto 20px;
 padding:20px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This made the trick. A jQuery script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var width = $(window).width();
  $('.pane-block-8').attr('style', 'width:' + width + 'px; left:-26.5% !important;');
});

$(window).resize(function () {
  var width = $(window).width();
  $('.pane-block-8').attr('style', 'width:' + width + 'px; left:-26.5% !important;');
});
```

Comment: Well, it almost did. Can't get it all the way to the left in all resolutions :(

Answer (score 0):

Overriding the **min-width** ( **min-width:100%** ) stopped the container from growing to the size of the contents.

**Details:**
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/fieldset informs:
"Unlike almost any other element, the WHATWG HTML Rendering spec suggests 
**min-width: min-content** 
as part of the default style for , and many browsers implement such styling (or something that approximates it)."