# Inner div width/height to 100% body size not parent div with side JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a base layer on top of which I have more multiple layers.
On my second layer, I want its width to stretch out to the width of the body.

**Main Project:**

http://jsfiddle.net/ygXy6/694/

**What I've tried:**

I searched into: 
[Make div inside parent 100% width of body, not parent div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13511249/make-div-inside-parent-100-width-of-body-not-parent-div)

This Does work: http://jsfiddle.net/ygXy6/18/

But doesn't work with my project, probably due to my `parallax` JS, this is my outcome when I apply the above method: https://jsfiddle.net/epkevxps/

I also tried using `vw` as one of the width units which leads me to think that i need to change my JS rather than CSS

My desired outcome would be for layer two to be 100% in width and layer three at 100% height: [like this *static* example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HtEb8.png)

Comment: Have you tried adjusting the position to get what you are looking for?

Comment: @cameron.townsend adjust which element exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

https://jsfiddle.net/mcxwnwy3/

I suggest you start fiddling with `vh` and `vw`. A better solution would be to make all elements siblings and use the `z-index` property instead of nesting them. That way you can use % for all elements.